# using python ctypes pass a long vector by reference to a c++ function

Tags: c++11, vector, pass-by-reference, ctypes, long-integer

Am trying to pass an empty vector of type long by reference to a c++ function as an argument from python using ctypes.

Im using python3 and c++11 compiler.
I've tried passing a ctypes.c_void_p pointer but it gives the wrong result.

test.cpp

```
extern "C" {
 int pke_decrypt(char *a,char *b,vector<long> &v)
  {do something;
   assign v;
   }}
```

test.py

```
_p=ctypes.CDLL('/home/electrical/Downloads/src/libpke.so')
 _p.pke_decrypt.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))]
 def decrypt(input1,input2):
    global _p   
    v=ctypes.c_void_p()
    print (v)
    result=_p.pke_decrypt(input1.encode('utf-8'),input2.encode('utf-8'),ctypes.byref(v))
    print (v)
    return
```

I'am expecting to get a random sized array(which is computed in the c++ function) of type long as output. That is, the size of the resultant vector is not predefined, else i could have used numpy.ndpointers() and defined a return type and returned a dynamically allocated array from c.

Comment: Note that it's ***c**types* not ***c++** types*.

Comment: well it worked with c++ as well

Comment: According to your answer, it didn't *OOTB*. You had to do an additional step (converting it to a *C* type in *test.cpp*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed char* by reference to c++  and it worked:

test.py

```
_pqc=ctypes.CDLL('/home/electrical/Downloads/src/libpke.so')
_pqc.pke_decrypt.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)]
 def pke_decrypt(input1,input2):
     global _p
     v=ctypes.c_char_p()    
     result=_pqc.pke_decrypt(input1.encode('utf-8'),input2.encode('utf-8'),ctypes.byref(v))
     print((v.value).decode("utf-8"))
     return
```

test.cpp

```
int pke_decrypt(char *input1,char *input2,char* &vout){
   Internal conversion from char* to vector<long> 
}
```